# When should I use a custom equality function in useSelector()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to understand when it is necessary to use a custom equality function in [`useSelector()`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector).

I have a selector that returns a simple object as:

```
const data = useSelector(state => state.data) // => { a: "foo", b: "bar" }
```

I though that since `data` is an object, I needed to use a custom equality function to avoid unnecessary re-render, as it is stated [in the doc](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates):

> With useSelector(), returning a new object every time will always force a re-render by default.

But then I noticed that my component was only re-rendering when `data` changed. I assumed that maybe the default equality function works with objects, but to be sure I tried to use a custom function:

```
const data = useSelector(state => state.data, (a, b) => a === b));
```

If `data` didn't change, it will always return `true`.

In Javascript, if I try to compare two objects with `===` it will return `false` because the references are different. But here with `useSelector()`, since it returns `true` it means that the references are the same.

**Now, I'm not sure if I misunderstood the doc, but I wonder when I should use a custom equality function such as the [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) of Lodash?**

I'm using Redux Toolkit, if it makes any difference. Here is a [CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-tess-wi1uxx?file=/src/App.js) if you want to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You should *rarely* need to write a custom equality function for `useSelector`**.

*Most* of your `useSelector` calls should either be a simple `const item = useSelector(state => state.slice.item)`, or be pass in [an existing memoized selector function](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors) like `const someData = useSelector(selectSomeData)`.

*If* you need to pass in a custom equality function, the most common one would be the `shallowEqual` function exported from React-Redux itself.

If you think you need to use a deep equality check like `_.isEqual`, you should probably pause and reconsider *why* you think you need a deep equality check, because that should normally be unnecessary in a Redux app.

Additionally, I think there's a bit of a misunderstanding here.  Yes, `state.data` is an object, but it is a *reference* to an object in memory.  When your reducer updates, RTK+Immer will automatically create a *new* object reference, and thus `oldObject === newObject` will be `false` because two different objects are never `===` to each other.  That's why `useSelector` already uses a `===` comparison by default - immutable updates means that comparison is really fast and simple to do.

Comment: Humm okay, it clarifies things a bit. But do you have any example that would require a custom equality function? Because I can't find one.

Comment: As soon as you create a **new object** within the selector function.

Comment: @phry Okay, so like `({ data }) => ({ ...data })` for example. I noticed that if I use this selector inside a `createSelector` as: `createSelector(selectData, (data) => ({ ...data }));` the equality function is still not required. Does is mean that if I ever come across this case I should use `reselect` instead of the equality function?

Comment: If you do that, the equality function is definitely required, otherwise you will have rerenders on completely unrelated dispatches. As for reselect vs equality function - that is totally up to you, reselect becomes only really necessary on calculation-expensive operations.